# Use jQuery ajax call PHP with json return and try to build a list from the json object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am using the following code to call PHP to get json back and trying to parse the json object returned and make a list of hyperlinks. I got json object back from PHP but my list was empty. Please help! Here is my jQuery code and json return

```
html code
<div id="document_list"></div>



function GetDocListMain() {
   var html='';
   $.getJSON("getUserDocument.php?id=" + <?php echo $_GET["id"] ?>,
       function(data){
       alert(data);
       $.each(data, function(index, item){
         html +='<li><a href="download_doc.php?id=' + item.id +'">' + item.file_name + ' | ' + item.created + '</a></li>' ;

       });
   });

   $('#document_list').empty();
   $('#document_list').append(html);

}
```

And my json return from PHP is

```
[ {"id":"1", "file_name":"testfile1.pdf", "created":"2017-02-11"},
  {"id":"2", "file_name":"testfile2.pdf", "created":"2016-11-12"},
  {"id":"3", "file_name":"testfile6.pdf", "created":"2016-10-12"}
]
```

Comment: `$.getJSON` is [**asynchronous**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). Move the two lines `$('#document_list').empty();` and `$('#document_list').append(html);` into  the callback right after `$.each`!

Comment: can you add the php code which produces the json object to the question. It will help to answer your question.

Comment: **Note:** the `div` with the id of `#document_list` should be an `ul` or `ol`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is async that's why its not working because you appending empty html before fetching json data. append your html inside success callback of `$.getJSON`

```
  function GetDocListMain() {
       var html='';
       $.getJSON("getUserDocument.php?id=" + <?php echo $_GET["id"] ?>,
           function(data){

           $.each(data, function(index, item){
             html +='<li><a href="download_doc.php?id=' + item.id +'">' + item.file_name + ' | ' + item.created + '</a></li>' ;

           });
           $('#document_list').empty();
           $('#document_list').append(html);
       });


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use $.each and oh! you have to append your HTML inside the AJAX call

```
function GetDocsListMain(){
   var html='';
   $.getJSON("getUserDocument.php?id=" + <?php echo $_GET["id"] ?>,
       function(data){
          alert(data);
          for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
          html +='<li><a href="download_doc.php?id=' + data[i].id +'">' + data[i].file_name + ' | ' + data[i].created + '</a></li>' ;
       }
       $('#document_list').empty();
       $('#document_list').append(html);
   }

}
```

Comment: `$.each` is fine.

Comment: for loop is simply better than $.each in this context

Comment: I use $.each(data, function(index, item){ ...... } . Because if there are two json object return. I can do the following.                                      $.each(data.datasetA, function(index, item){ ...... }                           $.each(data.datasetB, function(index, item){ ...... }